# Free screencast software (other than Screencast-o-matic) that allows trimming/truncating in real-time

Tags: screen-recording

I am working with Windows 10 on a Surface Book 2. I generally use Firefox, but am open to any browser.

I need screencasting software (online or desktop) to create videos for my job. Requirements are to be able to: 1) embed a webcam video into the screencast, and 2) truncate/trim the video in real-time (this requirement is the main point of this post).

To-date, I have been using [Screencast-o-matic](https://screencast-o-matic.com/), which I generally like because of its feature that allows me to accomplish (2) above: You can pause a video, watch it, and start re-recording at that point. It refers to this as "truncating" the video before you start re-recording. In summary, you can trim/truncate (albeit only from the end) *while making the video* (so you don't have to edit *after* the fact). This is great if you mess up and want to re-record a portion before continuing on. It's also *generally* user-friendly, allows you to save the file as an .mp4, etc.

The problem is Screencast-o-matic is *finicky*. Sometimes if I try to record fullscreen/almost fullscreen, the menu (where you start/stop recording the video) "disappears" behind my Windows start menu/taskbar. It's also inconsistent at allowing me to minimize the software itself to access applications in the background/"behind the recording" (which is often needed when you are editing the video in real-time (as I explained earlier), so you can "reset" your screen to the correct place before you start re-recording). Sometimes it also just won't launch from the website even after repeated attempts.

I've used this software for over a year, but it's often been a headache, and seems to be worse some days than others (the inconsistency in its performance might be the most maddening part). Also, I'm an educator and want my students to make a screencast for a project, and was going to have them use this software. However, I now don't think I can ask them to given how buggy it is (I couldn't even begin to explain to them the work-arounds I've implemented while using it...). The problem is I *cannot* find any other free screencasting software that does what I described above: Allows you to truncate in real-time and start re-recording. I have looked at probably 20 other applications, and NONE have this feature.

Does anyone know of any software that does what I described above (allows you to truncate/trim from the end in real-time and start re-recording, with webcam embedding being preferred as well)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [OBS](https://obsproject.com/)? It has tonnes of features and works well in a live environment. It also works cross platform and is open-source. And if you are missing something you might find a script to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I have not. I will look into it. If it has the ability to trim/truncate from the end in real-time, that will be great. Thanks!